# Join+Limit

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблицы table_1 и table_2, в которой связь на table_1 (пусть table_1_id). На table_1 может ссылаться несколько записей table_2.
Если что, то table_1 - это товары, а table_2 - заказы.
Я делаю выборку из table_1 и:

```
... LEFT JOIN table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
```

Получаем например для одной записи table_1 - 10 присоединенных table_2. (на один товар 10 заказов)
Мне нужно выбрать 10 записей table_1 и все их заказы. Но LIMIT 10 действует на результирующую таблицу и выбирается по сути одна запись((
Как сделать выборку 10 записей table_1, не учитывая сколько присоединится записей table_2.
Может как-то подсчитать сколько присоединится и увеличить LIMIT на это кол-во. Или группировкой какой хитрой.

[image]

Здесь сделан LIMIT 10. TovarID - table_1, ZakazID - table_2. Видно, что выбралось по сути 4 товара, а надо 10.
Это по сути нужно для пагинации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 LIMIT 0, 10) vtable_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = vtable_1.id
```

или

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = vtable_1.id
WHERE table_1.id IN (SELECT id FROM table_1 LIMIT 0, 10)
```

Comment: @vanchester, действительно) Забыл про вложенные запросы. Спасибо!

Comment: @ray_ban, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

пробуй

```
SELECT id.tovar,*.table2
FROM table2, (SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 10) as tovar
WHERE table2.table_1_id=id.tovar
```